# Java - returning a BigDecimal from a function?

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I was wondering if I can actually return a BigDecimal from a function as I have not seen anything online about this. Is it because it's not possible or is it really just bad practice to do so? Attempting the code below results in "error: cannot find symbol [in MainClass.java]"

```
public BigDecimal foo(){
    return new BigDecimal(10);
}
```

Comment: Maybe you are missing a `import java.math.BigDecimal` .

Comment: There are many possible reasons for this error and without seeing [mcve] we can't tell for sure what is wrong. Use [edit] option to improve your post. For now I marked it as duplicate of [What does a “Cannot find symbol” compilation error mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25706216) which list of many reasons for that problem to appear.

Answer (score 4):

There's absolutely nothing wrong with returning a `BigDecimal` from a method. In fact, the JDK has several methods that do that. Chances are you're just missing `import java.math.BigDecimal`, or something to that effect.